# Python Pandas - Dividing data in one column by another if both are summarized using the groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following code that generates four columns as I intended

```
   df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue']) #not exactly sure what this does
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['First Purchase Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Purchase Date'], unit='s')


df['number_existing_customers'] = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['Existing Customer']].sum()
df['number_new_customers'] = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer']].sum()
df['Rate'] = df['number_new_customers']/df['number_existing_customers']

Table = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'Rate', 'revenue']].sum()

print(Table)
```

I want to be able to divide one column by another (new customers by existing) but I seem to be getting zeros when creating the new column (see output below).

```
 >>> print(Table)
      New Customer  Existing Customer  Rate   revenue
Year
2014          7.00               2.00  0.00 11,869.47
2015          1.00               3.00  0.00  9,853.93
2016          5.00               3.00  0.00  4,058.53
2017          9.00               3.00  0.00  8,056.37
2018         12.00               7.00  0.00 22,031.23
2019         16.00              10.00  0.00 97,142.42
```

Comment: `df['column1']/ df['column2']` and if you want new column: `df['new_col'] = df['column1']/df['column2']`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure your assignment back to the DataFrame is working how you expect. On the left, you have your original DataFrame, with whatever the index is. On the right, the result of `groupby` will be a DataFrame indexed by the group keys, in this case 'Year'. So when you assign it back, it will only assign where the original DataFrame's index overlaps, which given a RangeIndex might be like rows around 1990-2017 if the dates are anything reasonable. Either way, this likely isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks ALollz.  The out put is as desired and the code is working as I expected it to. 
Quang Hoang, your proposed code gives me an error that says "NotImplementedError: operator '/' not implemented for bool dtypes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is define the column and then use the corresponding operator, in this case `/`:

```
Table['Rate'] = Table['New customer']/Table['Existing customer']
```

In this example I'm copying your `Table` output and using the code I've posted:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Year':[2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019],'New customer':[7,1,5,9,12,16],'Existing customer':[2,3,3,3,7,10],'revenue':[1000,1000,1000,1001,1100,1200]}
Table = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Year')
Table['Rate'] = Table['New customer']/Table['Existing customer']
print(Table)
```

Output:

```
      New customer  Existing customer  revenue      Rate
Year
2014             7                  2     1000  3.500000
2015             1                  3     1000  0.333333
2016             5                  3     1000  1.666667
2017             9                  3     1001  3.000000
2018            12                  7     1100  1.714286
2019            16                 10     1200  1.600000
```

Comment: Ivan, I tried this but seem to be getting zeros in my data.  I have revised my original code to include this above.

Comment: If you try this with the dataframe named `Table` you shouldn't get any problems. I've edited my answer to fit the dataframe `Table`

Comment: I still get all zeros for the Rate

Comment: Did you remove `_` which I mistankly put in my code. Also, if you do: print(table.info()) are columns `'New customer'` and `'Existing customer'` of type int/float?

Comment: Got it. The problem was I had added the Table['Rate'] calc before the Table=df.groupby line but it should be after.

Comment: Indeed, I'm glad we could sort it out!